# proc runs in SSMS, but not when call by SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a stored proc that runs in SSMS in about 18 minutes (yes, not the speediest, but that's another story)  However, when I call that same stored proc from an SSIS package, in runs till the DB times out (last attempt I killed after 4 hours).  Now, both the proc and the DTSX package were pre existing to my change ( I merely made a few where minor Where clause changes)

I know I'm passing in all the same parameters and connecting to the same database/Server.

The parameters are quite strange, 3 of them are comma delimited strings that get turned into tables once in the proc.  While it was not done before, I did reassign all parameters to local variables to avoid parameter sniffing.

Anyone have an idea of what could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: parameter sniffing was my first guess.  Next step is run profiler to verify that SSIS is constructing the parameters the way you think it is.

Comment: Also consider adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the SP.

Comment: @TabAlleman: Where is the profiler?  I've never heard of this functionality.

Comment: In SSMS, it's in the Tools menu.  If you've never used it before you might want to google a tutorial or two to see how to use it effectively.

Comment: I've run into this before, and I think Eric is right on. SQL caches the compiled version of a stored procedure and there are only certain events which cause a recompile. SSMS runs the proc a different way and ignores the compiled version in the cache. Try sp_recompile.

Comment: So, it looks like OPTION (RECOMPILE) was the solution, it even sped the stored proc up to be even faster! (now it only takes about 20 seconds to run!)  If you post an official answer, I can mark it as correct.